# how to call and connect 1 table with 2 many to many table

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have this database

```
ALTER TABLE `Partcar` (
     `partcarID` Char(7) NOT NULL,
     `partcar_price` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
     `partcar_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `carIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PartcarID`)
      UNIQUE KEY `car` (`carID`)
      CONTRAINT carIDFK FOREIGN KEY (`carIDK`) REFERENCES car(`carID`)
      );

CREATE TABLE `car` (
      `carID` Char(7) NOT NULL,
      `name_car` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `car_price` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PCID`)
      );

ALTER TABLE `assembly` (
      `assemblyID` char(8) NOT NULL,
      `assembly_price` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `partcarIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `barbellIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`assemblyID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `partcar` (`partcarIDFK`),
      UNIQUE KEY `barbell` (`barbellIDFK`),
      CONSTRAINT `partcarIDFK` FOREIGN KEY (`partcarIDFK`) REFERENCES partcar(`partcarID`),
      CONSTRAINT barbellIDFK FOREIGN KEY (`barbellIDFK`) REFERENCES barbell(`barbellID`)
      );

ALTER TABLE `barbell` (
      `barbellID` char(10) NOT NULL,
      `name_barbell` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `carIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`barbellID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `car` (`carID`),
      CONTRAINT carIDFK FOREIGN KEY (`carIDK`) REFERENCES car(`carID`)
      );
```

So, with this 3 tables, im confused how to connect 3 of them and im thinking with `barbell` and `partcar` make Many-to-many relationship with `assembly`,

so this is the sample of value

assembly and car output

```
| Code Car(CarID) + Assembly   |
-------------------------
| C1234 - B123456              |
```

that code is a link to see the part.

car + part output

```
| No. | IDcar + IDpart  | Description | Price |
----------------------------------------------
| 1   | C1234 - A333    | Interior    | $1    |
| 2   | C1234 - B444    | Chassis     | $2    |
```

and about barbell output

```
| No. | IDcar    | ID Barbell | Description  | Price |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1   | C1234    |  1234-1111 |  Big Wheel   | $1    |
| 2   | C1234    |  1234-2222 |  Wide Wheel  | $2    |
```

OR

assembly and car output

```
 | Code Car + Assembly   | ID Partcar, ID barbell | Description | Qty
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 | C1234 - B123456       |                        | 96' Cougar  |   
                         |  A333                  | Interior    |  1
                         |  B444                  | Chassis     |  1
                         |  1234-1111             | Big Wheels  |  1
                         |  1234-2222             | Wide Wheels |  1
```

this is the table, so I just want to know, what relationship to make this and how to call them with PHP?

*description is name of car, part, and barbell. and code car is carID

*note : dont worry about the tables, I just want to know how to connect them and how to call it if the tables like this.

Comment: Just use `JOIN`.

Comment: What is `Code Car`? What is `Description`?

Comment: @Barmar ill fix it, if i just use join, how about the relationship? is that correct? or i must add something?

Comment: You need to create additional relation tables for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @Barmar hmm, im thinking about that. but, how call it in php? just use join like another table?

Comment: Yes, why would it be any different? `SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN relationtable r ON r.table1ID = table1.id JOIN table2 ON table2.id = r.table2ID`

Comment: @Barmar idk, maybe it will different since, it has row with different data from different table. ill try it, thanks